# Liquibase doesn't generate sql rollback sql to tag

Tags: sql, oracle, liquibase

I have a schema generate with liquibase 4.17.2.
My changelog start in this way:

```
<databaseChangeLog
        xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xmlns="http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog"
        xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog
        http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog/dbchangelog-latest.xsd">

    <changeSet id="vinit" author="system">
        <tagDatabase tag="vinit"/>
    </changeSet>
```

The tag "vinit" is correctly inserted into the DATABASECHANGELOG table as the image:
[image]

When I try to invoke the rollback-sql cli from terminal in this way:

```
liquibase --changelog-file=../../src/main/resources/db/changelog/changelog-master.xml --url=jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1523:ORCL --username=zzz --password=xxx --output-file=afile.sql rollback-sql --tag=vinit
```

The error I have is Unexpected error running Liquibase: Could not find tag 'vinit' in the database

I tryed with --tag="vinit" and the same error occoured.

My database is Oracle 12c running into a docker container. Liquibase update-sql works perfectly.

Any help is appreciated.

I tryed with --tag="vinit" and the same error occoured,
My expectation is to have the rollback sql.

**SOLVED:**
***It didn't work due to a mismatch between the path used in the rollback-sql command and the path stored in the databasechangelog table. The rollback-sql command only works when using the same path. Damn!***

Comment: you need to add the tag first see https://docs.liquibase.com/commands/change-tracking/tag.html